# convergence of a sequence involving greatest integer function

Tags: analysis

$$a_n=\frac{1}{n}\left[n\beta\right]+n^2\beta^{n}$$where $0\lt\beta\lt1$

Now since $[n\beta]=n\beta- \{n\beta \}$, we have $$a_n=\beta-\frac{1}{n}\{n\beta\}+n^2\beta^{n}$$

$$\implies a_n-\beta=n^2\beta^{n}-\frac{1}{n}\{n\beta\}\lt n^2\beta^{n}$$. All I need to do now is show $n^2\beta^{n}\lt \epsilon.$

This is where I am getting stuck.

Comment: I hope $|\beta| <1$!

Comment: You prove it has an upper bound but you forgot to prove it also has a lower bound. It's necessary to prove convergence,

Comment: Consider β lying between  { (k-1)/n , k/n} for $k = 1,2,.,n.$ For different β you have different answers.

Answer (score 1):

if $|\beta| <1$ then you should compare $\beta^n$ with $n^2$. just look at $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\beta^{-n}}{n^2}$. Then just use l'Hopital's rule (probably twice). This should teach you that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\beta^{-n}}{n^2}=\infty$, therefore $\beta^n n^2$ will converge to $0$ if $n \to\infty$. The philosophy behind examining this fraction is finding out which one is 'faster' the polynomial expression $(n^2)$ or the exponential expression $(\beta^n)$.